# How to pass common data (region, currency, language) to segment.io using analytics.js

Tags: javascript, analytics, segment-io

For some background, we're integrating with https://segment.com/docs/ on our e-commerce site.

Our site currently has 3 regions (US, CA and UK).

The region is identified by different url paths, (e.g. /* (US), /ca/* (CA), /uk/* (UK)).

We define a `locale` object depending on which region you visit, e.g.

```
// A user who visits /uk/* will have this locale
const locale = {
    region: 'UK',
    currency: 'GBP', // one day this may be configurable
    language: window.navigator.language // en, en-US, en-GB etc.
}

// A user who visits /* will have this locale
const locale = {
    region: 'US',
    currency: 'USD', // one day this may be configurable
    language: window.navigator.language // en, en-US, en-GB etc.
}
```

We'd like to have our `locale` data associated with segment API calls (track, page, identify, etc.)

---

I can see 3 potential options:

1. Add `region`, `currency` and `language`* to the `context` object. e.g.

   ```
   window.analytics.track('Button Clicked', {}, {
     context: {
       region: locale.region,
       currency: locale.currency,
       language: locale.language
     }
   });
   ```

   - This would allow all API calls (track, page, identify, etc.) to associate the call with the current locale.
   - I expect this should be done via analytics.js middleware?
   - *I know the [context spec](https://segment.com/docs/connections/spec/common/#sts=Context) already defines `locale` which is equivalent to our `locale.language` (e.g. en-US), so we could set `context.locale: locale.language` instead of `context.language: locale.language`.

My main concern with the above is I'm not 100% sure it's acceptable to add our own data to the `context` object, [the documentation](https://segment.com/docs/connections/spec/common/#sts=Context) merely says "so properties outside the spec are ignored", however I expect our data warehouse could still utilise these extra properties?

Therefore, an alternative approach is to perhaps treat it as a user `trait` instead:

2. Call `identify` anonymously on page load with our locale as `traits` e.g.

   ```
   window.analytics.identify({
       region: locale.region,
       currency: locale.currency,
       language: locale.language
   });
   ```

   - Having tested this out it appears identified traits aren't sent along with subsequent events (track, page, etc.)

     - Therefore, I think we'd have to additionally pass our `locale` data as [`context.traits`](https://segment.com/docs/connections/spec/common/#sts=Context) via some middleware for all other calls?

My concern with this 2nd approach however is, given our `locale` data is temporal (the user could navigate to a different region at any time / it's not stored against a user record in a DB), it perhaps doesn't belong as a user 'trait'?

3. Define a separate segment.io `source` for each region e.g.

   ```
   window.analytics.load("REGION_SPECIFIC_WRITE_KEY");
   ```

   - I'm not sure whether this is safe given they all live on the same domain?

Is there a recommended design for this?

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks, I couldn't work out how to set context in a track call. Your question answered it for me :-)